# ASP.NET MVC 4 error with Google CalendarAPIv3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net, google-api-dotnet-client

I try this:

```
var auth = new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(controller, 
                                       new FlowMetaDataCalendarV3())
           .AuthorizeAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

AuthorizationCodeMvcApp execute fine, but AuthorizeAsync throw a exception in NewtonSoft.Json:

> [NewtonSoft.Json.JsonreaderException] --> {"Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '', line 1, position 72."}

I currently installed:
Google.Apis.Auth vrs 1.9.0
Google.Apis.Auth.MVC 1.9.0
NewtonSoft.Json 6.0.4

How to resolve this??

Comment: Can you please attach the HTTP request and response (using Fiddler or some other tool that exposes the real HTTP traffic). Did you follow our documentation at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications? By the way, try to use the async version as suggested in the documentation.

Comment: Yes i follow that documentation.

But when try to use await, get a compilation error, because the method AuthorizeAsync dont have the async identifier.

I think that is not the source of the problem.

Comment: What was the compile error? Can you attach Fiddller output?

Comment: Compilation Error:
    -------- Cannot await Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Web.AuthorizationCodeWebApp.AuthResult
    
    --------- The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: Fiddler:--- Host: 28.client-channel.google.com
    Connection: keep-alive
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
    X-Origin: https://talkgadget.google.com
    X-Goog-AuthUser: 1
    Authorization: SAPISIDHASH 1419355182857_132464e1553d544879da3439cbb372b41fb98977
    Accept: */*
    X-Client-Data: CJa2yQEIpbbJAQiptskBCMS2yQEInobKAQjviMoB

Comment: You didn't declare the method to be async: "public async Task IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JArray.Parse()` in stead of `JObject`.

Comment: I not use NewtonSoft directly. That exception rise in the execution context of Google.Apis.Auth.MVC 1.9.0